# Workbook_Open sub won't run when I open the workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

This program is supposed to create a button that the user can press to activate a different sub. From my searches online, it seems that the sub below should activate when opening up the workbook, but it's not?

What am I doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim btn As Button
Dim rng As Range
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = .Range("B2:C2")
        Set btn = .Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
    With btn
        .Caption = "To begin the program, please click this button"
        .AutoSize = True
        .OnAction = "TableCreation1"
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have this module placed in the `ThisWorkbook`object in the VBE, as opposed to a Module or Worksheet object? Because when I did that, it worked for me. In order for Workbook Events to fire, code has to exist in the `ThisWorkbook` module. Same for worksheet level events, the code needs to be in each sheet's object in the VBE.

Comment: @Scott, I think you should change your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Make sure your **Private Sub Workbook_Open()** subroutine is pasted inside of the **This Workbook** object and not in a Module, Form, or Sheet object.

Comment: Could you mark me as the right answer then? :)
(I'm trying to answer questions to get full access to the site!)

Answer (score 7):

The solution I found was running the below code and then the "Open" event worked.

```
Sub EventRestore()

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked for me. During a rendering subroutine, it disables EnableEvents to stop it triggering itself as it updates cells, and turns it back on afterwards. Something in the rendering sub broke and it left EnableEvents off. This setting seemed to be saved into the document, so it's impossible to turn it back on automatically as no events would even run to do it! I think having to `On Error` everything that turns it off to set it back to on is required in case of unexpected errors absolutely shafting your entire spreadsheet.

Comment: This was the solution for me as well. I'm using LibreOffice Calc to open Excel spreadsheets that have an "on open" event to hide a title page. One spreadsheet didn't fire the event. I tried a sheet I'd just opened that had worked, and now it wasn't working anymore either. Running this macro fixed things. The difference seems to be that Calc saves the EnableEvents globally somewhere instead of in the spreadsheet. Perhaps this is a result of/bug in the VBA compatibility layer.

Answer (score 6):

Interesting.
In 2009 a conflict with conditional formatting of the sheet to open is described, as in 
[vbforum post](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?555092-RESOLVED-Workbook_Open-event-won-t-run&s=237c4345d8c14bcd1d9cf5204b75005d&p=3431224&viewfull=1#post3431224).

It seems that this bug still exists in excel and prevents the `workbook_open` event from being fired.
I have a workbook (old XLS-binary format) that simply does not fire the event in Excel 2003 and 2007 but does in 2013. I deleted all conditional formatting from the first worksheet but could still not get the `workbook_open` procedure to run in elder Excel-Versions.

A Workaround, I use in distributed workbooks is to use a local variable and a second event in the workbook as follows:

```vb
''
' private variable
Private wbOpenEventRun as Boolean

''
' procedure to be called by excel when workbook opens
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    wbOpenEventRun = true
    ' perform tasks
End Sub

''
' the selection change event fires usually.
' performance is not reduced
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not wbOpenEventRun Then Workbook_Open
    ' perform tasks in reaction of selection change events, if required
End Sub
```

Comment: Dirty hack... Hats off! This solution seems to work!! I was having the same problem, but this seems to nail it! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

I know this post has been dormant for a while, but I just struggled for hours to solve this problem.  It's the oddest thing, but I finally noticed that one of my worksheets was in "Page View"... and as soon as I put it into "Normal" my Workbook_Open() function started working as normal again.  VERY STRANGE - definitely a Excel bug...  just glad I finally solved it...  Hope it helps someone...

Answer (score 1):

My solution was kind of obscure, and I don't even remember now why it occurred to me as a potential solution. The file I created in which the Workbook_Open() macro would not run, I originally created through the following steps:

1. Right clicked in the relevant folder, clicked **New**, clicked **Microsoft Excel Worksheet**.
2. Named the file "**Workbook_1**".
3. Opened **Workbook_1**.
4. File, Save As, changed file type to **Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)**, Save.
5. Wrote VBA code including a **Workbook_Open()** nested in **ThisWorkbook**.

For whatever reason, I wondered if my problem had anything to do with the fact that the file "started as" a standard **.xlsx**. So I simply:

1. Opened a new blank Workbook within Excel (**Book1**).
2. File, Save As, input **Workbook_2**, changed filed type to **Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)**, Save.
3. Copied VBA code and structure from the original **Workbook_1**.

Unlike the original **Workbook_1**, the new **Workbook_2** successfully ran the **Workbook_Open()** sub on open. Maybe a potential cause of this problem is related to the file's type history (i.e. if it was at some point a type that cannot run macros). Or maybe simply trying again with a new file is what solved this problem for me. Either way, this may work for anyone for which other solutions did not.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Nazim's event enable via code solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45839807/1915920) I found out the following fix:

## the fix

**closing all excel workbooks and VBA windows and reopening the one with `Workbook_Open()`** solved it.
(likely due to the event enabling similar to Nazim's solution linked above).

## problem experience

As I was debugging and aborted execution, I disabled the events in the running code before abort. I did not notice this circumstance at first and even after close/reopen of my workbook it did not work...

## probable cause

...The other open excel workbooks or some global instance somehow "remembered" that the events of the reopened workbook had been turned off.