# Auto open macro for a template

Tags: vba, excel

I've a custom menu I want to load upon an Excel template opening.

With just the standard xlms file I utilize the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    CreateMyMenu    - adds menu to the Add-in ribbon
End Sub
```

This works great.

When I save the file as an xltm file (Excel template) the `workbook_open()` sub no longer triggers when opening the template.

Comment: Have you checked everything - I created a workbook with a 'Private Sub Workbook_Open()'.  It worked as an XLSM and when I saved it as a template it opened Book11 and Book12 and ran the code ok.
Definitely an Excel Macro-Enabled Template (*.xltm)?  Macro security not too high?  I'm using 2010.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your VBA code (in a macro), you need to write that code again or import the file of it.

VBA codes in Excel will `Export` with these extensions:

- `*.bas` for your `Module` as `Basic File`.
- `*.frm` for your `UserForm` as `Form File`.
- `*.cls` for your `Class Module` as `Class File`

When you want them you need to `Import` them ;).

`File > Export File ...`

`File > Import File ...`

Comment: Not sure I understand your response.  What do I need to do to trigger my createmymenu macro when a user opens a new workbook using the template?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    CreateMyMenu    - adds menu to the Add-in ribbon
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that by placing it in the workbook and it failed, when I moved it to a module  it worked for me.
thanks,
JIm

Answer (score 0):

See the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369762/workbook-open-sub-wont-run-when-i-open-the-workbook). Make sure that the

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
... 
End Sub
```

is within the **ThisWorkbook** Excel Object, and not the Sheet.