# Workbook_Open sub won't run automatically when the workbook is opened

Tags: vba, excel

I need this macro to run when the .xlsm workbook is opened.  It only runs if I manually run the macro, it does not start when the workbook is opened.  FYI, I've checked/verified macro security (this is not signed yet).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Workbook\_Open sub won't run when I open the workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369762/workbook-open-sub-wont-run-when-i-open-the-workbook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to be located in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

1. Open the VBA Editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)
2. Open the Project Explorer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
3. In the Project Explorer pane, double click `ThisWorkbook`. (If you have multiple workbooks open, make sure you choose the `ThisWorkbook` under the correct project.)
4. In the code editor pane, click the drop-down that says `General`.

This will bring you to a new (or existing) `Workbook_Open` procedure:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

That's where your code should be placed.

---

Note that clicking the *other* drop-down at the top-right of the Code Editor pane, will list the other Workbook-level procedures you can add.

---

### More Information:

- Chip Pearson :  [**Code Module And Code Names**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/codemods.htm)