# Error 1004 when running macro in another workbook via Application.Run

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of Report Templates. Each Template calls a CommonMacroMR, which resides in the Documents - Folder. The executed code resides in ThisWorkbook Module.

When opening the report, immediately Excel comes up with

> Run-time error '1004':
> Cannot run the macro 'CommonMacroMR.xlsm!Workbook_Open'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

There is only one line of code in the `Workbook_Open` Sub of the report template:

```vb
Sub WorkBook_Open()
    Application.Run ("CommonMacroMR.xlsm!Workbook_Open")
End Sub
```

In Trust - Center / Macro Settings, following Setting is activated:

Enable all macros
Trust access to the VBA project object model

Comment: Would it be a better idea to call the macro from a regular module, instead of the workbook module? it's called `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` for a reason, to just run when the workbook opens.

Comment: I inserted a Module and pasted the code in, but it doesn't matter, the Workbook is not opened.

Comment: `Workbook_Open` is private by default. Did you make it public in CommonMacroMR.xlsm?

Comment: it wont work... workbook_open is always in a Private Sub, you cant declare it as public, or am i wrong

Comment: @RWatermelon Then how exactly are you intending on calling it?

Comment: OK, I now declared the Workbook_Open procedure as Public Sub. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use open method for CommonMacroMR.xlsm

```
workbooks("CommonMacroMR.xlsm").open
```

Comment: right, you are pointing at the exact problem: the workbook is not opened at the moment the code is executed. the code SHOULD open it, but it doesnt. Workbooks only references workbooks that are already opened. But thanks for the input :)

Comment: I can point out, that Application.Run opens the correct workbook, but the workbook_open procedure is not executed.

Comment: Maybe this helps  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369762/workbook-open-sub-wont-run-when-i-open-the-workbook

Answer (score 0):

`workbook_open` is called even if you use `workbooks.open` to open another file. However, you need to ensure that events are not disabled in your routines.